# How to make the mechanics of sticking a 2d object to an object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please tell me how you can implement the mechanics of sticking a 2d object to another 2d object with an auto-guide. In this example below there is such a mechanic, how to do it in Unity?
https://mathigon.org/tangram

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have code for a system like this, I can at least describe how I'd approach it. Assuming you would want it to be all predetermined, I would use colliders on the corners and sides as anchor points to snap to other anchor points. [Here's a good example from the Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/runtime-snapping-objects-together-based-on-anchor-points.961659/) where someone had a similar problem solved. I would start here. While it's 3D, I think it should still help provide a starting point.

In the future, you should provide more context to your question as well as what you have tried already. StackOverflow is good for solving more specific problems rather than providing a whole system. We need to know more about what you've tried so far to help you with what you're stuck on.